# Affecting a parent object from a frame page

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Parent Window that contains a frame with a main menu page.  I need that page and any other pages within the frame to communicate to an object of the main window.

How exactly can i accomplish this?  Do I need to use delegates?

Comment: @phadaphunk  Not much, I haven't a whole lot a of experience with C#.

Comment: Here is my setup, I have an abstract form object with several specific forms.  This main form object is used to hold data across multiple pages.  i'd like to keep this form object at the parent window level and effect it from any page that might be up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest solution would be to create new class file

```
Class MainWindowAccesser
{
    public static MainWindow mw;
}
```

and then and in MainWindow constructor set

```
MainWindowAccesser.mw = this;
```

Comment: Quick question, I have done this but I get an unresolved symbol with MainWindow, do I need to use a specific namespace?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I used `MainWindow` which I use every time for what is in your case your Parent Window class name

Comment: How do i utilize this then?  does the child use mw.parentobject?

Comment: You use `MainWindowAccesser.mw.OBJECTYOUWANTTOACCESS`. If it's still confusing you can upload the code so I will do it in your code

Comment: That works but I have another issue I guess.  I create a basic form object and as a part of one of the events I do this:  Basicform = new SpecificForm, it appears that when i use this method MainWindowAccesser.mw.BasicForm still treats it as if it were still a basic form and not the specific form.

Comment: We don't want to spam in this question so contact me thepeuj@gmail.com if you want further help (as you mentioned in comment above)